# Force Flutter Android Application to behave like it is on an iOS Device

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Is there a way to force an Flutter Android App to behave like it is on an iOS Device?

I'm not referring to the Cupertino package.

Here is what I mean with Android/iOS Style

iOS Style:

[image: ios]

Android style:

[image: Android Style]

Comment: You can create a custom toolbar with title in center.

Comment: I'm talking about the whole application and not only the the app bar.

Comment: Even if you could ,you shouldn't do it. iOS users don't find those style familiar. We should stick to native platform styles.

Comment: I'm not asking if I should do it. It's just for testing purposes. So I don't know why I get down voted for asking a question if it is possible.

Comment: Its a valid question and it is possible. See my answer below.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still don't know why I get downvoted by people.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the [platform parameter](https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/platform.html) in the ThemeData of the app to TargetPlatform.iOS. Then the app will behave as if it were running on an iOS device, including showing iOS text controls, etc.  Very useful for testing things out at least!

Here's a full app that will use iOS stylings even when run on an Android device:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        // The line below forces the theme to iOS.
        platform: TargetPlatform.iOS,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: TextField(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

*Edit*

If you also want to fake `defaultTargetPlatform`, you can do that by setting [debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride](https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride.html).  Including that as well we have:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';


void main() {
  // This line will fake defaultTargetPlatform to iOS.
  debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = TargetPlatform.iOS;

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        // The line below forces the theme to iOS.
        platform: TargetPlatform.iOS,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: TextField(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Updated with a full example app.

Answer (score 5):

##### Update

This is not valid anymore with latest Flutter version

##### Solution from Previous Versions

Yes, it is possible during development stage, if that is what you want.

If the App is started from Intellij/Android studio, open `Flutter Performance` tab from Intellij/Android Studio, there you can find the option `Platform` and you can toggle it between iOS and Android.

If you are launching app from command line and using flutter devtools, in Devtools Web Interface, go to tab `Flutter Inspector`, there you can find the option `Platform` and you can toggle it between iOS and Android.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @ChennaReddy  I cannot see "Platform" in "Flutter Performance" of "Android 4.1".

Comment: @DarioDigregorio  I cannot see "Platform" in "Flutter Performance" of "Android 4.1".

Comment: @TonyBrand it seems like the button to choose the target platform has been removed from Android Studio. But there should be still the possibility to set the platform in the property. See the Answer of Justin McCandless.

Answer (score 3):

Use `debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride` to force it, obviously in debug:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = TargetPlatform.iOS;

    return PlatformApp(
      title: 'Lovey-Dovey',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Lovey-Dovey2'),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Flutter will default the style to the native platform. So iOS/Android apps, while maintaining similar functionality, won't look out of place on the phone as they will follow Cupertino/Material guidelines respectively.