# Flutter inspector toggle platform mode is not showing

Tags: flutter, flutter-devtools

I am using android studio and I can't find toggle platform mode in the flutter inspector. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just set the platform [parameter](https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/platform.html) in the ThemeData of the app to TargetPlatform:

```
platform: TargetPlatform.iOS
```

Code example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        // The line below forces the theme to iOS.
        platform: TargetPlatform.iOS,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: TextField(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58042717/force-flutter-android-application-to-behave-like-it-is-on-an-ios-device)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted